# Flutter - How to convert Map<String, String> from TextEditingController to a Map<String, dynamic> JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have about 40 TextFormFields and I retrieve their values with TextEditingController. The values are converted into a Map<String, String> map via the following step:

```
// map that stores controllers
Map<String, TextEditingController> storeControllers = controllers;

// convert to map that stores only controller texts
Map<String, String> currentSelections = storeControllers
      .map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, storeControllers[key]!.text))
```

The current output with all values in String type:

```
//currentSelections map
Map<String, String>
{
    "field1": "1",
    "field2": "Two",
    "field3": "0.03",
     ...
    "field40": "four40",
}
```

How do I convert the currentSelections map into a JSON that stores the values in their corresponding types?

```
//Desired output:
Map<String, dynamic>
{
    "field1": 1, //int
    "field2": "Two", //String
    "field3": 0.03, //double
    ...
    "field40": "four40", //String
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

I understand that the way to convert Strings to other types is using `int.parse("text")` method. But how do I do it with so many different types involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try with this

```
Map<String, dynamic> convert(Map<String, String> map) {
  return {
    for (final entry in map.entries)
      entry.key: int.tryParse(entry.value) ??
          double.tryParse(entry.value) ??
          entry.value
  };
}
```

Example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, String> map = {
    "field1": "1",
    "field2": "Two",
    "field3": "0.03",
    "field40": "four40",
  };

  final newMap = convert(map);

  print(jsonEncode(newMap));

  //output: {"field1":1,"field2":"Two","field3":0.03,"field40":"four40"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method to go through each element and cast it if necessary.

```
bool isInt(num value) => (value % 1) == 0;

final Map<String, dynamic> desireddMap = currentMap.map((key, value) {
    dynamic newValue = value;

    // Check if value is a number
    final numVal = num.tryParse(value);
    if (numVal != null) {
      // If number is a int, cast it to int
      if (isInt(numVal)) {
        newValue = numVal.toInt();
      } else {
        // Else cast it to double
        newValue = numVal.toDouble();
      }
    }

    return MapEntry(key, newValue);
  });
```